# Save file in background by Kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

In my android app in ViewModel

```
 private fun finishProcessRecognizedCheck(
        firebaseVisionImage: FirebaseVisionImage,
        firebaseVisionText: FirebaseVisionText, recognizedCheck: Check
    ) {
        val file_prefix = resultRecognizedCheckList.size.toString()
        RecognizedCheckDataService.saveRecognizedImage(firebaseVisionImage, file_prefix)
        RecognizedCheckDataService.saveRecognizedText(firebaseVisionText, file_prefix)
       }
```

as you can see I save image file to internal folder in **UI thread**.
As result the application is freeze. 
Is it possible to save image on **background** by Kotlin's coroutines?
AA

Answer (score 1):

A coroutine requires a scope to run on. So, we create a scope using a dispatcher and a job.

1. Define a job and create a scope using the job you created and a dispatcher, like this:

   ```
   //Initialization of job
   private var job = Job()

   // Initialization of scope for the coroutine to run in
   private var scopeForSaving = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.Main)
   ```
2. Now we fire off the saving action upon a button click, like this:

   ```
   private fun saveButtonClick() {
           scopeForSaving.launch { saveToStorage() }
   }
   private suspend fun saveToStorage(){
           withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                 //Logic for saving the image goes here
           }
   }
   ```
3. We can cancel the job in `onDestroy()` so that when the activity is destroyed, we can be sure that all coroutines are terminated.

   ```
   override fun onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy()
       scopeForSaving.cancel()
   }
   ```